# Spring AMQP - Pass ListenerContainer to bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, amqp, spring-amqp

I am currently trying to pass the Spring AMQP Listener Container to a bean, because I need to change the maximum number of listeners dynamically (but I have memory limits, so I need more control than the listener container offers me out of the box).

My idea was to create a bean manageListenerContainer that is called every second or so and changes the concurrentConsumers attribute accordingly.

But I can not figure out how to pass the listenerContainer to my bean, 
as the id attribute was removed from rabbit:listener-container some versions ago.

This is my listener container:

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    error-handler="exHandler">
    <rabbit:listener ref="foo" method="listen" queue-names="myQueue" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

And the bean where I want to inject it:

```
<bean id="manageListenerContainer" class="background.ManageListenerContainer">
    <property name="listenerContainer" ref="listenerContainer"></property>
</bean>
```

I figured out I could instantiate a new listenerContainer like this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer" id="listenerContainer">
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

But this is not the same object than the connection itself uses.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

olli

Answer (score 1):

That nested `rabbit:listener` tag has an `id` for that purpose.

The enclosing `listener-container` is just logical representation for common properties. The real `ListenerContainer` is really based on that `rabbit:listener`.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
<!-- TODO: Find a more awesome way to get the parameters. -->
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
    username="#{ T(String).valueOf(systemEnvironment['CLOUDAMQP_URL']).split(&quot;//&quot;)[1].split(&quot;:&quot;)[0]}" 
    password="#{ T(String).valueOf(systemEnvironment['CLOUDAMQP_URL']).split(&quot;:&quot;)[2].split(&quot;@&quot;)[0]}" 
        host="#{ T(String).valueOf(systemEnvironment['CLOUDAMQP_URL']).split(&quot;@&quot;)[1].split(&quot;/&quot;)[0]}" 
virtual-host="#{ T(String).valueOf(systemEnvironment['CLOUDAMQP_URL']).split(&quot;@&quot;)[1].split(&quot;/&quot;)[1]}"/>

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="myQueue" />

<bean id="foo" class="Foo" />
<bean id="exHandler" class="BackgroundRejectingErrorHandler" />

<bean class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter" id="messageListenerAdapter">
    <constructor-arg ref="foo" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer" id="listenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="queueNames" value="myQueue" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListenerAdapter" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="150" />
    <property name="startConsumerMinInterval" value="10" />
    <property name="stopConsumerMinInterval" value="10" />
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="exHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="manageListenerContainer" class="background.ManageListenerContainer">
    <property name="listenerContainer" ref="listenerContainer"></property>
</bean>
```